# AVG: Biber listed as a trojan in TexLive 2014?

Tags: biber, security

A few days ago I installed TexLive 2014 on Windows. I just compiled a document today to test it and Biber is recognized as a Trojan Horse by AVG Free. The message says: BackDoor.Generic18.ALDX. From my research online, this seems to be fairly strange since I could not find any other similar questions on that topic. What could then be wrong? If I ignore the threat, it pops up again at the next compilation.

Comment: I did the same and checked biber.exe as well as the whole win32 folder including all *.exe files of texlive 2014, using „Avira Professional Security“, last update today. No findings, nothing. So maybe you can provide the mirror where you have installed from? Or you upload your biber.exe to a website where it can be checked as well?

Comment: I can confirm that AVG Free detects Biber as Trojan Horse. In my case, it's biber.exe from MikTeX. I made an online test with https://www.virustotal.com/de/. There, AVG detects a Trojan Horse also, but all 50 something other scanners detect nothing. So, I would say it is a very annoying false positive from AVG.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm '...a very annoying false positive...' -- but, I'm sure, not half as annoying as a false negative. :)

Comment: @Brent.Longborough a true word ;-)

Comment: I am seeing the same thing.  Downloaded 2014/06/29 texlive 0.4.5 r.1280 and saw this as an error under AVG 2014.0.4716 with virus database version 3986/7791.  I want to trust tex live, but following recent malware issues with source forge I am concerned.

Comment: Also finding a worm in another tex live file.  Given that this distribution is a compilation of many different packages from many different sources there are many possible vectors for attack.

Comment: I've submitted here: http://samplesubmit.avg.com/

Comment: @Ben What have you submitted? A request?

Comment: @kzarns Do you actually mean a worm? Not another trojan? (There are lots of ways the latter could be a false positive - I'm not sure about worms.)

Comment: @cfr after quarantining biber.exe, AVG reported a worm in a file within tex live other than biber.exe.  Unfortunately I did not catch the name of the file or any other details.  I'm sure AVG logs that somewhere so I will see if I can find the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, as others point out various different tests all indicate that this is a false positive. I have just added exceptions in `AVG` for `biber.exe` and the containing file within `texmf`, which seems to have dealt with the issue for now.