# Biber.exe infected by Trojan BackDoor.Generic18.ALDX

Tags: miktex, biber

My antirus software AVG 2014 just detected that there seem to be a Trojan in the biber.exe program which was last updated on June 6, 2014 and is in the package miktex-biber-bin.
Has anybody else had the same problem?

Comment: is this related to [AVG: Biber listed as a trojan in TexLive 2014?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187759)

Comment: yes, i have the same trouble. I tried to update miktex from mirror.switch.ch this morning and AVG 2014 also detected the trojan Backdoor.generic18.aldx.

Comment: Would an antivirus software be detecting a false positive? I doubt it. More probably bas only been picked up by AVG.

Comment: @Xavier_B False postives are certainly possible: I wonder here about the fact that Biber contains a 'self unpacking' Perl system to allow it to work.

Comment: @Xavier_B False positives from AVG? Lotsa!